# Go routine returns less results then the actual result

Tags: go, goroutine, waitgroup

I have a LOOP that does the hashing inside for a given key and returns the result, but on Result, If I have 1500 list of URL that goes inside LOOP, it never returns the result of 1500, it returns always lesser then 1500.

What am I doing wrong in below:

```
if len(URLLists) > 0 {
    var base = "https://example.com/query?="
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var mutex = sync.Mutex{}
    wg.Add(len(URLLists))
    for _, url := range URLLists {
        // wg.Add(1)  OR above for loop
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            hmac := "HMAX_123"
            out := encoding.HexEncodeURL(hmac, url)
            final := base + out
            list := Lists{
                Old: url,
                New: final,
            }
            mutex.Lock()
            response.URL = append(response.URL, list)
            mutex.Unlock()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    jR, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err != nil {
        w.Write([]byte(`{"success": false, "url" : ""}`))
    } else {
        w.Write(jR)
    }
    return
}
```

I tried both method for `Add` - one inside loop by 1 and one outside loop by total length.

I want function to return all 1500 URL list and not just "700, 977, 1123" random list.

It looks like - `wg.Wait()` is not waiting for all the `wg.Add` - added

Comment: What happens if you add `url:= url` before the go routine or better yet, parameterize the Go routine

Comment: Hopefully: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

Comment: @DazWilkin - that solved the problem

Comment: @DazWilkin - Thank you so much for sharing the knowledge. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in this program:

1. You are using the loop variable inside the goroutine. The loop variable is rewritten at each iteration, so when the goroutine uses the `url`, it might have already moved on to the next URL, thus you end up with multiple goroutines hashing the same URL. To fix:

```
    for _, url := range URLLists {
        url:=url // Create a copy of the url
        // wg.Add(1)  OR above for loop
```

2. You have a race condition. You have to protect access to `response.URL` because it is being written by multiple goroutines. You can use a mutex:

```
lock:=sync.Mutex{}
for _,url:=...
  ...
  lock.Lock()
  response.URL = append(response.URL, list)
  lock.Unlock()
```

A better way would be to send these over a channel.

Comment: that did solve the problem, I added url inside `go func(url string)` and initialized it `}(url)` is this the better way to do it? or shall I do your way? `url:= url`?

Comment: Both ways work. The important thing is to copy the  loop variable so the goroutine can access that copy, not the updated `url`.

Comment: Thanks! I marked the answer complete :) Thank you so much for sharing the knowledge.

Comment: With regards your question on which approach is better, adding the parameter to the go routine is clearer. It shows that the function takes `url` as a value, avoids the implicitness of the closure and is easier to refactor. For example, it's then easier to pull the nameless/lambda function out, name it, test it (in isolation) and reuse it elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

You have a pretty serious race condition here:

```
response.URL = append(response.URL, list)
```

If you're starting as many as 1500 concurrent Go routines, you will have many hundreds of them all attempting to execute this line at once. They will be constantly overwriting changes to the array.

You need to protect the insertion of new data into this slice with a `sync.Mutex`, or be sending results over a channel and having a single Go routine reading from that channel and appending to the list.

Comment: If I use `mutex lock and unlock` for insertion inside `go` won't that slow down or an equal effect of not having go routine?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not? You would have to measure, but it's irrelevant. You *need* to synchronize appends to that variable, period. Performance doesn't matter if your program produces incorrect results.

Comment: I completely agree, thank you so much for the insights @meagar - I added the mutex lock.

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, you're also missing a `url := url`

Comment: that did solve the problem, I added `url` inside `go func(url string)` and initialized it `}(url)` is this the better way to do it? or shall I do the above way? `url:= url`?

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the knowledge :)

Comment: @Rockabee, passing functions via parameter is a great way to explicitly define variable scope.  Whilefunction literals' inherited scope is sometimes crucial, you'll write more easily tested, debugged, and modified code if you try to limit use of functions' inherited scope to a minimum.  Prefer global function definitions which inherit no scope, and you'll find your code easier to comprehend and safely change.  I would prefer your method to `url := url`.